# Detect which sim is sending sms in dual sim phone android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'm making an app which sends messages to clients through a registered number.But i'm unable to find a way to detect if the user is sending sms through the same registered number.I knew getLine() in telephonyManager but sometimes it reurns null.any other ways to do it?

Comment: Which Android version is your app running on?